# Lisp Coerce and Set function explanation

Tags: lisp, set, quote, coerce

I try to do this directly to the interpret:

```
(setf example (coerce "blablabla" 'list))
```

and works fine. Infact `(car example)` returns #\b

but if I try this:

```
(defun myfun (string) ( (setf example (coerce string 'list))))

(myfun "blablabla")
```

I don't get the same!

How can I fix?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remove the extra parentheses around the `setf` in the `defun`:

```
(defun myfun (string)
  (setf example (coerce string 'list)))
```

Now you'll get the same. Note that the outer parenthesis have meaning. In Lisp, either it is quoted, or must be a function call. If the first element is, as in this case, a list, it cannot be a function to call, hence the error.

Comment: oh! nice! what a stupid error... It drove me crazy!!! Thank you for your patience!